# Laravel: redirecting with input doesn't work for array inputs

Tags: arrays, redirect, input, laravel

I have a form with an array input like this

```
<input name='websites[]'/>
<input name='websites[]'/>
<input name='websites[]'/>
```

Now in the controller I want to go back with inputs if the validation fails. I use this common laravel instruction:

```
if($validator->fails()){
    return \Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator->messages());
}
```

But I get the error "Expecting string, array given". Of course.
Is there a solution or should I handle array inputs myself?

Comment: is it typo, or do you really have this `name='[]websites`?

Comment: Sorry it was a typo. just fixed it :-D

Answer (score 0):

standard way of doing this is

```
    $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);

    if ($validator->fails())
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
```

no need to explicitly add the `->messages()`

**EDIT**
From the comments, it is obvious that this answer will not help all, since as user deczo said, `->withErrors()` accepts a Validator instance and takes appropriate MessageBag, or if provided, the MessageBag itself.

Comment: True, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @deczo Really? You mean, the error will still be present?

Comment: Yes. The problem is that Laravel don't autofill form fields form Input data of array type.

Comment: I don't know about the error, since OP didn't specify, what causes that error ;) Anyway, it's how `withErrors` works - it will grab `MessageBag` from the `$validator` implementing appropriate interface, or, if provided with `MessageBag`, it will just process it (and `MessageBag` is what `->messages()` returns)

Comment: Ok. But now the fact is that `withErrors` doesn't cause me any problem. `withInput` does since it has to handle some input of type array :-)

Comment: @Thiezar there is no way to do that with Laravel's Form helper. Taylor Otwell stated, that he's not gonna do anything with Html/Form Builders, so unless community do something with it, it won't be doable. For now, do it yourself, that's what I'd suggest

Comment: Oh, what a pity. Ok, so I'll do it myself. 
I'll go like this:

`return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput(Input::except('websites'))->with(['websitesOldInput'=>Input::get('webisites')]);`

what do you think? Is this a good way?